# Installing my app and it crash on start-up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

My game engine is unity and I build it in android platform. Installed in Motorola android phone but when I start my app it says "Game Name" has stopped. I use Android Device Monitor to check for error  and here is the log can someone  points out what is the error?

```
09-14 08:51:47.410: I/ActivityManager(984): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity bnds=[127,476][240,602] (has extras)} from uid 10021 on display 0

09-14 08:51:47.416: V/WindowManager(984): Set focused app to: AppWindowToken{81f14cc token=Token{bb4f61e ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475}}} old focus=AppWindowToken{da26fb0 token=Token{423b562 ActivityRecord{5e12c2d u0 com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.GoogleNowPanel t4462}}} moveFocusNow=true

09-14 08:51:47.418: V/WindowManager(984): findFocusedWindow: Reached focused app=AppWindowToken{81f14cc token=Token{bb4f61e ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475}}} target=AppWindowToken{da26fb0 token=Token{423b562 ActivityRecord{5e12c2d u0 com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.GoogleNowPanel t4462}}}

09-14 08:51:47.459: V/WindowManager(984): findFocusedWindow: Reached focused app=AppWindowToken{81f14cc token=Token{bb4f61e ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475}}} target=AppWindowToken{da26fb0 token=Token{423b562 ActivityRecord{5e12c2d u0 com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.GoogleNowPanel t4462}}}

09-14 08:51:47.460: I/ActivityManager(984): Start proc 3571:com.bluemountain.drstage/u0a97 for activity com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity

09-14 08:51:47.622: W/ActivityManager(984):   Force finishing activity com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity

09-14 08:51:47.627: V/WindowManager(984): Set focused app to: AppWindowToken{da26fb0 token=Token{423b562 ActivityRecord{5e12c2d u0 com.motorola.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.GoogleNowPanel t4462}}} old focus=AppWindowToken{81f14cc token=Token{bb4f61e ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475}}} moveFocusNow=true

09-14 08:51:48.130: W/ActivityManager(984): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475 f}

09-14 08:51:48.167: I/WindowManager(984): Failed to capture screenshot of Token{bb4f61e ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475 f}} appWin=Window{29ffd0 u0 Starting com.bluemountain.drstage} drawState=4

09-14 08:51:48.356: D/SystemServicesProxy(1090): getRecentTasks:TASK = id=4475 stackId=1 user=0 lastActiveTime=1568422307628 componentComponentInfo{com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}/isExcluded = false/includeFrontMostExcludedTask = false/isFirstValidTask = true/t.id = -1

09-14 08:51:48.357: D/SystemServicesProxy(1090): getRecentTasks:TASK = id=4469 stackId=1 user=0 lastActiveTime=1568420403104 componentComponentInfo{com.unity3d.genericremote/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}/isExcluded = false/includeFrontMostExcludedTask = false/isFirstValidTask = false/t.id = 4469

09-14 08:51:48.374: D/ComponentInfo(1090): return value labelRes is:New Unity Project
09-14 08:51:48.376: D/ComponentInfo(1090): return value labelRes is:New Unity Project
09-14 08:51:58.491: W/ActivityManager(984): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{8784a59 u0 com.bluemountain.drstage/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t4475 f}
```

I'm using unity version 2018 and jdk is embedded in unity

Comment: This looks like the problem "Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord"

Comment: @HassanVoyeau i tried checking for that error but can't find one for unity.

Comment: Found the problem its in the admob scripts. will update on this